# Old question with edited and not accepted answer now is the correct

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, outdated-information

C# updated to version 7.3, and now `Enum` types are accepted as generics.

I was looking for a way to parse some `Enum`s and found that an old question ([How do I cast generic enum to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960555/how-do-i-cast-generic-enum-to-int/51025027#51025027)) had the answer for previous language versions, and the second most upvoted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51025027/2215451) was updated to reflect the new solution.

I upvoted the second answer, but I'm afraid that people looking for a solution about the 7.3 version will not scroll down, thereafter, they will keep on looking around, or create a new question.

By the way, the accepted answer solves the problem for older versions, so I don't think that it should be downvoted.

Besides upvoting the second answer, what more we could do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing else needs to be done.

Both answers are correct for a particular set of constraints.

Some users may need the older answers, and may find those more useful. Express your own opinion with your votes, and feel free to leave comments pointing out the answers differences, if something like that doesn't already exist.

Regarding the acceptance mark, nothing to be done. That's not something we can change or contest. When the OP asked their question, that was the most useful answer for them. They are free to change it, but I personally do not believe it is worth doing.